# My output sound on my laptop is really quiet however, I cannot change the output volume. Anyway to make my MacBook Air louder?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

so recently my MacBook Air has been very quiet. I do not know how this happened because I did not change anything in my settings. I cannot hear anything until the volume is half way up and it is still very quiet on full blast. Is there anyway to fix this?? (This has been going on for about two weeks)

Answer (score 1):

If you have gone to System Preferences, Audio and everything seems normal, it’s time for a Genius Bar appointment.

Do not be like me and have all the audio panned to the left (it happened to me more than once and it’s very embarrassing). Ensure your “balance” is centered. Your device list will likely be different (I have a bunch of Audio interfaces) but still, you should have `Internal Speakers` selected (and maybe as the only option, that’s normal).

If balance is centered. If output volume is decent and you still can’t hear very well, there may be a hardware malfunction and the Genius Bar is *the way to diagnose it*.

[image]